# Why does the mouse cursor disappear while typing in tomboy?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04

In my laptop (under Ubuntu 10.10 upgraded from 10.04) the mouse cursor will disappear while and after I'm typing something in tomboy. This will also happen in google-chrome location bar. I think it could be some old config file errors. But I do not want to clean all my config files. So I'm wondering does anyone know what config file should be cleaned? Thanks~

Comment: Isn't this just working as designed? I know in Chrome on OSX the mouse cursor disappears as soon as you start typing in a box (as it has done with me typing this reply). It makes sense if your hands are on the keyboard that you dont want/need to see the mouse cursor, given you're not using it.

Comment: Well, the mouse disappearing way you mentioned is just OK for me. But in my case, the mouse will continue disappearing after I finished my tying, i.e., I move the mouse in the edit area without seeing the arrow/cursor. Currently, this only happens in google-chrome location bar and tomboy.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know for Tomboy but for Google-Chrome and Chromium this is the default behavior so rather of searching what config file should be cleaned you should search what option you need to change to make it work the way you want to.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, this is just how those applications work. So long as you are not seeing it in other applications, it is application specific, and probably not something you can change if the applications do not have settings that allow you to change that particular behaviour.